# Got some warnings when i build Cnosdb source code, how to fix?

Tags: cnosdb

Got some warnings when i build Cnosdb source code, how to fix?

**warning:** the following packages contain code that will be rejected by a future version of Rust: buf_redux v0.8.4, multipart v0.18.0, rustc-serialize v0.3.24
note: to see what the problems were, use the option `--future-incompat-report`, or run `cargo report future-incompatibilities --id 1`

Comment: Trust your compiler messages (especially Rust's, which are very good)! This is a warning, not an error, and the two options at the end of the message tell you how to dig into it further if you really feel the need to. If CnosDB don't fix that in their own dependencies by the time it becomes an error, you could always lock your toolchain version to whatever they're using.

Answer (score 1):

What did you do to build it? I don't know how to build so I tried `cargo build --bins`, and I can't see that warning.

- CS: Apple M1 Pro
- OS: Ventura 13.4

Comment: use makefile `make build`